# UISegmentedControl with 5-6 segments

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

In our application we are showing the segmented control with dynamic segments.

If number of segments is 2-3 we have no issue, but if number of segments is 5 or more than that then the text in segment is not readable.

[image: Segmented Control]

See the above image.

So, what is the alternate way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You need to tell us the usage of this to be able to suggest you an alternative.

Comment: An alternative way is to use icons instead of text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of solutions.

1. You could use a UIPickerView instead of a UISegmentedControl
2. You could show three segments, where the first two segments are the most often used segments, and touching the third segment shows a UIPickerView with all the options.
3. You could embed the UISegmentedControl in a UIScrollView. Make sure to size your segmented control in a way that shows that it is indeed scrollable.

Which one fits best depends on your app, and what is the actual use of those segments.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question on a general basis. Apple's Human Interface Guidlines may be a good reference for this kind of issues.

Comment: Hi I read Apple's HIG and it suggests to avoid more than 5 segments in a segmented control. So we have decided to change the design. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best Solution is that add `ScrollView` in you **view controller** and add `UISegmentController` to `UIScrollView` and give fix size of your segment button and change size of `UISegmentController` Base on **total numbers of button** and also change **content** size of `UIScrollView` base on `UISegmentController`.

Answer (score 0):

try setting font size for the test to be smaller, that ways, the text will be more visible.
However, if your number of segments keep increasing, that wouldn't be a solution